# Does Ubuntu Touch offer APIs for battery, installed apps enumeration, WiFi and cellular info, OS info, confinement info, etc?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development, battery

I'm in the progress of porting my existing 'droid app as a native Ubuntu Touch QML + QT5 C++ app. I've tried to find a native Ubuntu Touch or QT5 API for the following goals, but without a luck so far. As far as I understand, QtMobility is phased out, and QtSystemInfo is not (or not yet?) implemented. Am I out of luck, or are there some tricks or special ways to achieve these?

- battery properties detection, like current battery charge level, battery temperature (alternative to the green robot OS' BatteryManager)
- installed apps enumeration (alternative to PackageManager.getInstalledPackages)
- WiFi network and connection detection, like SSID, RSSI (alternative to WifiManager)
- cellular network and connection properties, like SIM state, network operator code (alternative to TelephonyManager)
- Ubuntu OS properties detection, like OS version/build, codename, etc. Similar to the information that's already available for unconfined apps in /etc/os-release
- state of confinement: whether the app is currently running confined via AppArmor, or "free" like when running it on the Desktop from Ubuntu SDK.

Please note that I intend to submit my app to the Ubuntu Store, so the app I'm developing has to work confined via AppArmor. Hence such tricks like using /sys filesystem to read battery info cannot be used. I also don't want to submit my app to the OpenAppStore, so packaging it to run unconfined is also not possible. I'd like to play by the rules of AppArmor.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Try a [scope](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/scopes/) or Explore the [Ubuntu SDK](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/platform/sdk/installing-the-sdk/)

Comment: I'm not sure how scopes would help about this issue. I've also installed and been using the Ubuntu SDK for weeks now already. I have of course gone through the Ubuntu QML API documentation, as well as studied QT5 on other sites. I haven't found any trace of the APIs I'm looking for though. The closest solution for e.g. the battery issue might be to implement QtMobility in one way or another, but as far as I can tell, it also reads battery info from /sys under Linux, which is prohibited when the app is confined via AppArmor :-(